# Android: Register another app as mediaButtonEvenReceiver

Tags: android

In Android, is it possible to register another app as the receiver for the media button events?

For example, say I want to start playing music from Google Play Music programmatically (ie: without leaving my app and launching Google Play Music). This is what I've tried:

```
ComponentName myEventReceiver = new ComponentName("com.google.android.music", "com.google.android.music.MediaButtonIntentReceiver");
AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
myAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(myEventReceiver);
// build the PendingIntent for the remote control client
Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(myEventReceiver);
PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
// create and register the remote control client
RemoteControlClient myRemoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
myAudioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(myRemoteControlClient);
```

I get this error, which makes sense:

```
registerMediaButtonEventReceiver() error: receiver and context package names don't match.
```

Is it possible to do some other way?

Answer (score 0):

My app playlist manager is able to launch google music. As long as google music has picked up the playlist itself through ascan, it plays the playlist. I have found though that it treats the playorder not as numeric but as text so 1, 10, 11,2.

```
  public void playSelectedPlaylist(String playlistname) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.ENTRY_CONTENT_TYPE,    "android.intent.extra.playlist" );
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, playlistname);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS, "vnd.android.cursor.item/playlist");

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        doToast("Sorry, no app was found to service this request", context);
    }
}
```

The intent is INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH and it finds all those apps that have this in their manifest.xml file. So far so good as Poweramp shows up.

Have a look at Playlist Manager by theoklink.
Google Play Music does play the playlist without any problems.